# Как применить Stylesheet для QScrollBar::vertical к QScrollBar::horizontal?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qss, qscrollbar

Имеется Stylesheet для `QScrollBar:vertical`. 
Как применить такой же к `QScrollBar:horizontal`?

Вот таблица стилей  `QScrollBar:vertical`:

```css
 QScrollBar:vertical
 {
     background-color: #2A2929;
     width: 15px;
     margin: 15px 3px 15px 3px;
     border: 1px transparent #2A2929;
 }
 QScrollBar::handle:vertical
 {
     background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);
     min-height: 5px;
     border: 2px solid white;
     border-radius: 4px;
 }
 QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical
 {
     margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: top;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }
 QScrollBar::add-line:vertical
 {
     margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: bottom;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }
 QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover,QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:on
 {
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: top;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }
 QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover, QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:on
 {
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: bottom;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }
 QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical
 {
     background: none;
 }


 QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical
 {
     background: none;
 }
```

Вот так выглядит сам `QScrollBar::vertical` после применения этого `styleSheet`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QScrollArea)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont

class TaskListWidget(QScrollArea):
   def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.content = QWidget()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.content)
        for _ in range(20):
            self.layout.addWidget(QLabel("Вот так выглядит сам QScrollBar::horizontal после применения этого styleSheet:"))
        self.setWidget(self.content)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tasklist = TaskListWidget()
        self.windowLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.windowLayout.addWidget(self.tasklist)
        self.setLayout(self.windowLayout)

qss = '''
 QScrollBar:horizontal
 {
     height: 15px;
     margin: 3px 15px 3px 15px;
     border: 1px transparent #2A2929;
     background-color: #2A2929;    
 }
 QScrollBar::handle:horizontal
 {
     background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);      
     min-width: 5px;
     border: 2px solid white;
     border-radius: 4px;
 }
 QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal
 {
     margin: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
     border-image: url(./images/right_arrow_disabled.png);       
     width: 10px;
     height: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: right;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }
 QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal
 {
     margin: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
     border-image: url(./images/left_arrow_disabled.png);        
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: left;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }
 QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal:hover,QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal:on
 {
     border-image: url(./images/right_arrow.png);               
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: right;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }
 QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal:hover, QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal:on
 {
     border-image: url(./images/left_arrow.png);               
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: left;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }
 QScrollBar::up-arrow:horizontal, QScrollBar::down-arrow:horizontal
 {
     background: none;
 }
 QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal
 {
     background: none;
 }

/**********************  vertical   **********************/
QScrollBar:vertical
 {
     background-color: #2A2929;
     width: 15px;
     margin: 15px 3px 15px 3px;
     border: 1px transparent #2A2929;
 }
 QScrollBar::handle:vertical
 {
     background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);
     min-height: 5px;
     border: 2px solid white;
     border-radius: 4px;
 }
 QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical
 {
     margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: top;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }
 QScrollBar::add-line:vertical
 {
     margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: bottom;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }
 QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover,QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:on
 {
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: top;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }
 QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover, QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:on
 {
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: bottom;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }
 QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical
 {
     background: none;
 }
 QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical
 {
     background: none;
 }
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кст, чтобы одинаковые стили для vertical и horizontal не повторять, лучше их перечислить через запятую: `QScrollBar:horizontal, QScrollBar:vertical { ... }`

Comment: @gil9red да, это так, но лень-матушка... … Она неистощима :)